# Apply Bevel/rounding to junction of two combined forms

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I'm looking for a special profile with a combination of two forms.

So that I can best manage the rounding/bevel of the junction of these two forms.

Is it possible and how can I get this result (see attached image)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether you're using subdivision - so these approaches may not be your way.... (all the operations are under a subdivision modifier, level 1 or 2)

[image]

1. starting with a cube, add some edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), to support its sharp edges, and to halve its sides. Then cut the diagonals you can see, using the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>).
2. bevel the central vertex (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)
3. inset the new face  (<kbd>I</kbd>) to make room for a bevel
4. extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) the inset face
5. maybe scale the top face (in my case, Z is up, so that's <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) the edge at the turn to the extrusion, adjusting the profile with the mouse wheel to increase divisions, (you could do that, and change the profile and offset of the bevel at the bottom of the toolbar region while the tool is active, if necessary.)

But as you can see, that results in sharp turn, not very like the profile you illustrate, and there's not much room to move edge loops around.

So the bottom row in my illustration doesn't use beveling at all, and just tweaks the heights  and scales of the horizontal edge loops on the dome.

Edit mode>edge ..<kbd>Alt</kbd> select an edge loop

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale it in XY

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide the loop up and down without significantly altering the profile

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to move it up and down and alter the profile

If the subdivision modifier's' "Display modifier in Edit mode" box is checked, you can visually adjust the modifier's result to your profile. But be aware, if the subdivision level is changed, the profile may fatten or shrink.

Comment: I've validated as an answer to my question, but I still have not managed to redo this again, because just a little reminder Robin :-) , I'm fully beginner and i've to look everywhere to reproduce:
- an 8-sided fan fill
... etc.

Just a small video screenshot would have been perfect but I don't want to take your time ;-)

Thank you Robin

Comment: My apologies. I'm not sure a specific gif would really help -  these are things you'll find yourself doing again and again, in different contexts - so I've expanded the steps in my answer. Which isn't definitive, either. There are many other approaches than this one, which is a traditional subdivision surface way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin for this more detailled reply!